# error with a constructor of a class, image attached

Tags: java, class, constructor

I try to define a new class with objects.. I don't know what is wrong with the constructor. 
the error is: "the constructor is undefined"
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you've `imported` the `Point` class in the `PointUser` file?

Comment: I think the message showing up in Eclipse (if this is Eclipse) would be different if that were the problem.

Comment: Is this Eclipse?  I can't see anything wrong.  Try cleaning your project and rebuilding.  By the way, please don't use your camera to take pictures of the screen.  If you're on Windows, there are ways to capture the screen image (Snipping Tool, under Accessories, is a good way to capture part of it).  We'd prefer you just post the code.  But if you really want to show things like the doodads and red lines that Eclipse displays, a screen capture would be much better.

Comment: What parameter are expected? I guess you imported [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) or sth. like that.

Comment: the program runs now I see. but why there are those errors in red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean the project... it seems ok, you are not importing anything, both classes are in the same default package.

To clean your project, go to the Project menu and select "Clean..." and hit OK.

[image]

Comment: I'm very new to java, what is to clean the project? and when is automotic building?

Comment: What errors? Also, if the class does not compile, it cannot run.